# Webpack 3.1. jQuery is added multiple times

Tags: jquery, django, webpack

After migration to Webpack 3, I have noticed that jQuery inclusion works not as I expected.

My template structure has *core/_global.html* root template in which I render common js and css assets like:

```
<head>
    {% render_bundle 'global' 'css' %}
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}

    {% render_bundle 'global' 'js' %}
    {% block header_javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</head>
```

Second level templates extend the root template and add additional js and css to html:

```
{% extends "core/_global.html" %}

{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% render_bundle 'accounts/register' 'css' %}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {% render_bundle 'accounts/register' 'js' %}
{% endblock %}
```

In previous verions of Webpack  at the beginning of global.js I had:

```
import 'expose?jQuery!expose?$!jquery'
```

After removing this line and changing webpack.config to:

```
   plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
   jQuery: "jquery",
  }),
```

I have following problem - each of the rendered files, global.js and register.js contain jQuery. As result the size of each file is increased by appr. 300 kb.

I expect jQuery should be loaded only once and it should be accessible both in global.js and register.js

Are there any workarounds which allow to include jQuery in such way and have access to it from different js files? Should I probably refactor the structure of templates? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/).

Basically, in newer version of Webpack I can use additional plugin CommonsChunkPlugin.Depends on the settings it extracts all the common js and css from all the chunks into the separate chunk. This chunk can be later used on html page.

What helped in my case:

**webpack.config.js**

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'commons',
  filename: 'commons.js',
  minChunks: 2
}),
```

**global.html page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "bundles/commons.js" %}"></script>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to upgrade this to the SplitChunksPlugin?